# jQuery /CSS - get position of relative element, position tooltip accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tooltip

I have a map showing various locations which when hovered over will show a tooltip next to the cursor revealing information regarding that location.

The map is a background image of the main ul id="map", with each location being a li. The location is positioned by css using top and left.

The #map is positioned relative and the tooltips are positioned absolutely.

The markup I have is as follows:

```
<ul id="map">
<li><a href="#" class="harewood tip_trigger"><img src="images/marker.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" /> <span class="tip"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" width="143" height="107" alt="" />Title<br />Click marker for details</span></a></li>
```

I can show and hide the .tip span using jQuery no problem, but I'd like to get the position of the parent .tip_trigger, and offset the tooltip from the cursor by, say, 10px.

How would I amend the jquery code below?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Tooltips
$(".tip_trigger").hover(function(){

var pos = $("#map").position();  
var width = $(".tip").width();

    tip = $(this).find('.tip');
    tip.show(); //Show tooltip
    tip.css({"left": (pos.left + width) + "px","top":pos.top + "px" });

}, function() {
    tip.hide(); //Hide tooltip
});
});
```

I've been messing with this for a while, have tried jquery documentation and just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

algiecas is right, I usually add an extra step with `each`

like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Tooltips
$(".tip_trigger").each(function () {
 $(this).hover(function(){

 // assuming you give the image the class marker
 var pos = $(this).find('marker').position();  

    tip = $(this).find('.tip');
    var width = tip.width();
    tip.show(); //Show tooltip
    tip.css({"left": (pos.left + width) + "px","top":pos.top + "px" });

 }, function() {
    tip.hide(); //Hide tooltip
 });


});
});
```

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciate you taking the time to look at this.

I should add that the #map has a set height and width, as the markers are about 20 in number, all positioned absolutely in various places on the map.

Using the code that Frank supplied, the tooltip isn't going relative to the marker, but to the map. In fact, all the tooltips that are showing on hover are going in exactly the same position.

Comment: var pos = $(this).position(); gives you the position of each tip_trigger, it should not have the same value, but add some alert(pos); to debug your javascript. i don't understand exactly which element you want the tooltip on

Comment: Thanks Frank. If I pop the alert(pos); into the hover function it gives me [object object].

The tooltip should be on the absolutely positioned marker.gif within the li. What I provided was a code snippet, there are about 20 other markers, in different positions.

I wish I could give you a url, but it's a development server. Here is a screenshot instead: [link](http://www.farstyle.com/map.jpg)

Comment: okay, then use: var pos = $(this).find('img').position(); instead, or, even better, add class="marker" to the marker image and use var pos = $(this).find('.marker').position();

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much Frank, that's working as I wanted it to, and learned something along the way too. Thank you.

Comment: happy to help... by the way check out the jquery plugin tiptip, which does very nice things (although I think it's good that you do it yourself first for learning purposes)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the position of the `.tip_trigger`, not the whole `#map`

```
var pos = $(this).position();
```